# How to show less.css in firebug while inspecting a page?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am currently running bootstrap3 with less.

I use less compiler to generate style.css(which is linked to bootstrap.less) and have it embedded into my page.

What I want to know is that.

when I inspected the page with firebug I noticed that under the style panel, there were only css information (e.g when I inspected the header, it showed the respective line in css -> bootstrap.css line 1)

I want it to show the related less line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome DevTools has support for CSS pre-processors such as LESS or Sass in the inspector.

See this article: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/css-preprocessors

Comment: Thanks Carlos! i went to a link you provided and try to understand but fail to do so... I also forgot to mention that I downloaded a free bootstrap3 template. When i inspect the elements in the page, it shows the related less.css line. What really interests me is that there are not less files in the template folder that i downloaded.. can you explain what is going on??? thx

Comment: The less.css file may be linked to a CDN or another external host. In that case, it won't be physically present in the template folder that you downloaded. Check the stylesheet `<link>` tag for the template to see where the Bootstrap framework is sourced from.